# iOS application not visible in macOS finder

Tags: ios, swift, macos-catalina, finder

Mac OS Catalina now supports iPhone/iPad sync via the Finder on the Mac.  Additionally, you can copy files to and from iOS application via the Finder. This is a very nice feature.

Unfortunately, my iOS application is not appearing in the Finder Files tab.

Do I need to package my app in XCode with a special capability to enable this feature?  Here is a shot of the Finder window on my Mac.  My app is not in the list.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may need to set the [`UIFileSharingEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uifilesharingenabled) (`Application Supports iTunes file sharing`) key in your app's `Info.plist` file.

Comment: May need? More like a must need and now I feel like a dufus for not finding this needle in the vast Apple haystack.   (Yes, I did my google due diligence before posting my question but apparently was not using the proper search words.)  Thank you, Andy, this is just what I needed!